# Dolby Vision Mp4 to HLS Stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, http-live-streaming

Is it possible to create a dolby vision HLS stream with ffmpeg? I have tried online tutorials such as this one https://codecalamity.com/encoding-uhd-4k-hdr10-videos-with-ffmpeg/#saving-dolby-vision but I have not seen any success. I either get hevc files with no dv from tsmuxer, invalid rpu files or the Skipping NAL unit 63 message from ffmpeg. Here is the current ffmpeg command I'm testing to at least get an hevc with dolby vision

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -f hevc - | dovi_tool extract-rpu --rpu-out input.rpu - | x265-10b - --input-depth 10 --output-depth 10 --y4m --preset veryfast --crf 22 --master-display "G(8500,39850)B(6550,2300)R(35400,14600)WP(15635,16450)L(40000000,50)" --max-cll "0,0" --colormatrix bt2020nc --colorprim bt2020 --transfer smpte2084 --dolby-vision-rpu input.rpu --dolby-vision-profile 8.1 --vbv-bufsize 20000 --vbv-maxrate 20000 output.hevc
```

I have also tried with dovi_tool like so

```
ffmpeg -i nameofmovie.mp4 -f yuv4mpegpipe -strict -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le - | x265-10b - --input-depth 10 --output-depth 10 --y4m --preset veryfast --crf 22 --master-display "G(8500,39850)B(6550,2300)R(35400,14600)WP(15635,16450)L(40000000,50)" --max-cll "0,0" --colormatrix bt2020nc --colorprim bt2020 --transfer smpte2084 --dolby-vision-rpu input.rpu --dolby-vision-profile 8.1 --vbv-bufsize 20000 --vbv-maxrate 20000 output.hevc
```

Which gives me this error:

```
[hevc @ 000002f047aaf1c0] Skipping NAL unit 63
    Last message repeated 1 times
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument00:00:00.04 bitrate=4772857.0kbits/s speed=0.297x
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=   24300kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=4772857.0kbits/s speed=0.261x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 5271783.500000%
Error closing file pipe:: Invalid argument
[hevc @ 000002f047cc0b80] Skipping NAL unit 63
    Last message repeated 8 times
[hevc @ 000002f047a23dc0] Skipping NAL unit 63
    Last message repeated 1 times
[hevc @ 000002f0480be640] Skipping NAL unit 63
    Last message repeated 1 times
Conversion failed!
```

Theoretically I'd like to go from mkv straight to HLS with dolby vision but that seems to be even more problematic.

Any suggestions?